# Parse netstat -s using regex in shell script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, networking

netstat -s gives output like below

Tcp:
12345 active connections openings
34345345 passive connection openings
3434 failed connection attempts
54545 connection resets received
5 connections established
**65565 segments received
575575 segments send out**
57 segments retransmited
10 bad segments received.
12121 resets sent.

From above output, I want to get number of segments received and segments send out in two separate variable.

I just started with shell, I have following code snippet, but not sure how can I proceed with regex

```
echo "${OUTPUT}"


re="(\d+) segments send out'"

if [[ ${OUTPUT} =~ $re ]]; then // not sure here how to extract number`
```

Comment: See https://ideone.com/bsWvXa

Comment: Thanks. It worked